# Android Studio Emulator: App won't run unless you update google play services

Tags: android-emulator

I am building an application that uses the google maps api.The first activity of the application is a maps activity, which refuses to run based on the error I stated in the title.

I have heavily modified my build.gradle trying to fix the problem; based on other solutions I found on this website.

But I think I may have made it worse:  This is what my build.gradle looks like:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.navigation.dixongardens.ben.bensgardens"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    // androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Can someone help guide me as to what is wrong with my build.gradle? I am confused as to which dependencies are required for google services to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue with your app, but an issue with your emulator. You need to update the emulator you are running / download a new system image and create an emulator from that.

The exception is telling you that Google Maps expects a newer version of Google Play Services than what is currently running on your device. Sometimes it will have a link to update google play services under the notification. (in the app on the google map view)

Comment: I just created a new emulator on API 27, and still the same issue occurs

Comment: Does it have google play services installed? Please post the exact exception you see in the log.

Comment: the log is clean except for:7:43 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: /home/benjamin/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_27.avd/userdata.img

Comment: do you have filters on / are you building a debug apk?

Comment: Sorry, I have not heard of filters, what does that mean? And when the apk compiles it is marked as a debug application

Comment: Thank you..  I found out that the specific image I had did not have google play services installed.  I feel so stupid now haha

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, only you need to click notification showing above message. Then google play service will be updated automatically. Easy

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)